# mysql index on orderby from 0 to 25 seconds

Tags: mysql, indexing, sql-order-by

I have this query that now requires about 0,57 seconds:

```
SELECT analisi0_.ID_ANALISI AS col_0_0_,
       paziente5_.ID_PAZIENTE_LAB AS col_1_0_,
       sessione1_.ID_GEL AS col_2_0_,
       patologico8_.patologico AS col_3_0_,
       tipovalida9_.TIPO_VALIDAZIONE AS col_4_0_,
       specie7_.specie AS col_5_0_,
       analisi0_.campione AS col_6_0_,
       analisi0_.tracciato AS col_7_0_,
       paziente5_.cognome AS col_8_0_,
       paziente5_.nome AS col_9_0_,
       paziente5_.DATA_NASCITA AS col_10_0_,
       sesso6_.sesso AS col_11_0_,
       sessione1_.NUMERO_SESSIONE AS col_12_0_,
       sessione1_.DATA_SESSIONE AS col_13_0_,
       metodica4_.metodica AS col_14_0_
FROM Analisi analisi0_
  INNER JOIN Sessione sessione1_ ON analisi0_.ID_SESSIONE = sessione1_.ID_SESSIONE
  INNER JOIN tipo_sessione tiposessio2_ ON sessione1_.ID_TIPO_SESSIONE = tiposessio2_.ID_TIPO_SESSIONE
  INNER JOIN metodica_tipo_metodica metodicati3_ ON tiposessio2_.ID_METODICA_TIPO_METODICA = metodicati3_.ID_METODICA_TIPO_METODICA
  INNER JOIN Metodica metodica4_ ON metodicati3_.ID_METODICA = metodica4_.ID_METODICA
  INNER JOIN Paziente paziente5_ ON analisi0_.ID_PAZIENTE = paziente5_.ID_PAZIENTE
  INNER JOIN Sesso sesso6_ ON paziente5_.ID_SESSO = sesso6_.ID_SESSO
  INNER JOIN Specie specie7_ ON paziente5_.ID_SPECIE = specie7_.ID_SPECIE
  LEFT OUTER JOIN Patologico patologico8_ ON analisi0_.ID_PATOLOGICO = patologico8_.ID_PATOLOGICO
  INNER JOIN tipo_validazione tipovalida9_ ON analisi0_.ID_TIPO_VALIDAZIONE = tipovalida9_.ID_TIPO_VALIDAZIONE
WHERE 1 = 1
AND   (paziente5_.nome LIKE 'MARIA%')
AND   (paziente5_.DATA_NASCITA IS NOT NULL OR paziente5_.DATA_NASCITA > 0)
LIMIT 20;
```

the problem is that adding this default order by:

```
ORDER BY sessione1_.DATA_SESSIONE ASC
```

the query is executed in 25 seconds.

the explain for the unsorted is:

```
id  select_type table   partitions  type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    filtered    Extra
1   SIMPLE  specie7_        index   PRIMARY SPECIE  137     1   100 Using index
1   SIMPLE  paziente5_      ALL PRIMARY,IDX_DATA_NASCITA,IDX_NOME,FK_PAZIENTE_SPECIE,FK_PAZIENTE_SESSO              690950  5   Range checked for each record (index map: 0x3B)
1   SIMPLE  sesso6_     eq_ref  PRIMARY PRIMARY 1   elettroforesi.paziente5_.ID_SESSO   1   100 
1   SIMPLE  analisi0_       ref FK_ANALISI_PAZIENTE,FK_ANALISI_SESSIONE,FK_ANALISI_TIPO_VALIDAZIONE FK_ANALISI_PAZIENTE 4   elettroforesi.paziente5_.ID_PAZIENTE    1   100 
1   SIMPLE  tipovalida9_        eq_ref  PRIMARY PRIMARY 1   elettroforesi.analisi0_.ID_TIPO_VALIDAZIONE 1   100 
1   SIMPLE  patologico8_        eq_ref  PRIMARY PRIMARY 1   elettroforesi.analisi0_.ID_PATOLOGICO   1   100 
1   SIMPLE  sessione1_      eq_ref  PRIMARY,FK_SESSIONE_TIPO_SESSIONE   PRIMARY 4   elettroforesi.analisi0_.ID_SESSIONE 1   100 
1   SIMPLE  tiposessio2_        eq_ref  PRIMARY,FK_TIPO_SESSIONE_METODICA_TIPO_METODICA PRIMARY 2   elettroforesi.sessione1_.ID_TIPO_SESSIONE   1   100 
1   SIMPLE  metodicati3_        eq_ref  PRIMARY,ID_METODICA PRIMARY 2   elettroforesi.tiposessio2_.ID_METODICA_TIPO_METODICA    1   100 
1   SIMPLE  metodica4_      eq_ref  PRIMARY PRIMARY 2   elettroforesi.metodicati3_.ID_METODICA  1   100
```

while the explain for the sorted version is

```
id  select_type table   partitions  type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    filtered    Extra
1   SIMPLE  specie7_        index   PRIMARY SPECIE  137     1   100 Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort
1   SIMPLE  paziente5_      ALL PRIMARY,IDX_DATA_NASCITA,IDX_NOME,FK_PAZIENTE_SPECIE,FK_PAZIENTE_SESSO              690950  5   Range checked for each record (index map: 0x3B)
1   SIMPLE  sesso6_     eq_ref  PRIMARY PRIMARY 1   elettroforesi.paziente5_.ID_SESSO   1   100 
1   SIMPLE  analisi0_       ref FK_ANALISI_PAZIENTE,FK_ANALISI_SESSIONE,FK_ANALISI_TIPO_VALIDAZIONE FK_ANALISI_PAZIENTE 4   elettroforesi.paziente5_.ID_PAZIENTE    1   100 
1   SIMPLE  tipovalida9_        eq_ref  PRIMARY PRIMARY 1   elettroforesi.analisi0_.ID_TIPO_VALIDAZIONE 1   100 
1   SIMPLE  patologico8_        eq_ref  PRIMARY PRIMARY 1   elettroforesi.analisi0_.ID_PATOLOGICO   1   100 
1   SIMPLE  sessione1_      eq_ref  PRIMARY,FK_SESSIONE_TIPO_SESSIONE   PRIMARY 4   elettroforesi.analisi0_.ID_SESSIONE 1   100 
1   SIMPLE  tiposessio2_        eq_ref  PRIMARY,FK_TIPO_SESSIONE_METODICA_TIPO_METODICA PRIMARY 2   elettroforesi.sessione1_.ID_TIPO_SESSIONE   1   100 
1   SIMPLE  metodicati3_        eq_ref  PRIMARY,ID_METODICA PRIMARY 2   elettroforesi.tiposessio2_.ID_METODICA_TIPO_METODICA    1   100 
1   SIMPLE  metodica4_      eq_ref  PRIMARY PRIMARY 2   elettroforesi.metodicati3_.ID_METODICA  1   100
```

the index on table SESSIONE:

```
Table   Non_unique  Key_name    Seq_in_index    Column_name Collation   Cardinality Sub_part    Packed  Null    Index_type  Comment Index_comment
sessione    0   PRIMARY 1   ID_SESSIONE A   44468               BTREE       
sessione    1   IDX_DATA_SESSIONE   1   DATA_SESSIONE   A   878             BTREE       
sessione    1   IDX_NUMERO_SESSIONE 1   NUMERO_SESSIONE A   168             BTREE       
sessione    1   FK_SESSIONE_TIPO_SESSIONE   1   ID_TIPO_SESSIONE    A   6               BTREE       
sessione    1   FK_SESSIONE_UTENTE_INSERIMENTO  1   ID_UTENTE_INSERIMENTO   A   1               BTREE
```

any suggest to speed up this default order by?

EDIT:

following the script to create the tables:

```
CREATE TABLE PAZIENTE
(
   ID_PAZIENTE          INT           UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   ID_PAZIENTE_LAB      VARCHAR(20),
   COGNOME              VARCHAR(40),
   NOME                 VARCHAR(40),
   DATA_NASCITA         DATE,
   ID_SESSO             TINYINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
   RECAPITO             VARCHAR(50),
   CODICE_FISCALE       VARCHAR(30),
   ID_SPECIE            TINYINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (ID_PAZIENTE), 
   INDEX IDX_DATA_NASCITA (DATA_NASCITA),
   INDEX IDX_COGNOME (COGNOME),
   INDEX IDX_NOME (NOME),
   CONSTRAINT FK_PAZIENTE_SPECIE FOREIGN KEY (ID_SPECIE) REFERENCES SPECIE(ID_SPECIE),  
   CONSTRAINT FK_PAZIENTE_SESSO FOREIGN KEY (ID_SESSO) REFERENCES SESSO(ID_SESSO)   
)
ENGINE=InnoDB;




CREATE TABLE ANALISI
(
   ID_ANALISI               INT             UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   ID_PAZIENTE              INT             UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
   ID_SESSIONE              INT             UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
   TRACCIATO                TINYINT         UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
   CAMPIONE                 VARCHAR(30),
   ID_PATOLOGICO            TINYINT         UNSIGNED,
   REPARTO                  VARCHAR(40),
   TOTALE_PROTEINE          FLOAT,   
   RAPP_AG                  FLOAT,
   ID_ANALISI_LINK          INT             UNSIGNED,
   ID_ANALISI_IFE           INT             UNSIGNED,   
   ID_ANALISI_DATI          INT             UNSIGNED,  
   ID_ANALISI_NOTA          INT             UNSIGNED,
   DATA_MODIFICA            DATETIME,      
   ID_UTENTE_MODIFICA       SMALLINT        UNSIGNED,
   DATA_VALIDAZIONE         DATETIME,
   ID_TIPO_VALIDAZIONE      TINYINT         UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
   ID_UTENTE_VALIDAZIONE    SMALLINT        UNSIGNED,   
   DATA_CANCELLAZIONE       DATETIME,
   ID_UTENTE_CANCELLAZIONE  SMALLINT        UNSIGNED,      
   PRIMARY KEY (ID_ANALISI), 
   INDEX IDX_CAMPIONE (CAMPIONE),
   INDEX IDX_PAZIENTE (ID_PAZIENTE),
   INDEX IDX_SESSIONE (ID_SESSIONE),
   INDEX IDX_REPARTO  (DATA_MODIFICA),   
   CONSTRAINT FK_ANALISI_PAZIENTE             FOREIGN KEY (ID_PAZIENTE)             REFERENCES PAZIENTE(ID_PAZIENTE),
   CONSTRAINT FK_ANALISI_SESSIONE             FOREIGN KEY (ID_SESSIONE)             REFERENCES SESSIONE(ID_SESSIONE),
   CONSTRAINT FK_ANALISI_PATOLOGICO           FOREIGN KEY (ID_PATOLOGICO)           REFERENCES PATOLOGICO(ID_PATOLOGICO),
   CONSTRAINT FK_ANALISI_TIPO_VALIDAZIONE     FOREIGN KEY (ID_TIPO_VALIDAZIONE)     REFERENCES TIPO_VALIDAZIONE(ID_TIPO_VALIDAZIONE),
   CONSTRAINT FK_ANALISI_UTENTE_MODIFICA      FOREIGN KEY (ID_UTENTE_MODIFICA)      REFERENCES UTENTE(ID_UTENTE), 
   CONSTRAINT FK_ANALISI_UTENTE_VALIDAZIONE   FOREIGN KEY (ID_UTENTE_VALIDAZIONE)   REFERENCES UTENTE(ID_UTENTE), 
   CONSTRAINT FK_ANALISI_UTENTE_CANCELLAZIONE FOREIGN KEY (ID_UTENTE_CANCELLAZIONE) REFERENCES UTENTE(ID_UTENTE),    
   CONSTRAINT FK_ANALISI_ANALISI_LINK         FOREIGN KEY (ID_ANALISI_LINK)         REFERENCES ANALISI(ID_ANALISI),
   CONSTRAINT FK_ANALISI_ANALISI_IFE          FOREIGN KEY (ID_ANALISI_IFE)          REFERENCES ANALISI_IFE(ID_ANALISI_IFE),
   CONSTRAINT FK_ANALISI_ANALISI_NOTA         FOREIGN KEY (ID_ANALISI_NOTA)         REFERENCES ANALISI_NOTA(ID_ANALISI_NOTA),
   CONSTRAINT FK_ANALISI_ANALISI_DATI         FOREIGN KEY (ID_ANALISI_DATI)         REFERENCES ANALISI_DATI(ID_ANALISI_DATI)
)
ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Comment: Is this a duplicate of the one where you were shown to have a too-small `innodb_buffer_pool_size`?

Comment: I still have the problem with 2GByte assigned to mysql on a i5 with 4GByte , i also tried to use the date on table analisi to simplify the query, also this column indexed, with 1.6M rows on Analisi and 0.8M rows on Paziente, following query requires 5 seconds without order by and 75 seconds with order by, I think I will try to use integer instead of datetime to store my timestamp  -->  SELECT 
analisi0_.ID_ANALISI
FROM Analisi analisi0_
  INNER JOIN Paziente paziente1_ ON analisi0_.ID_PAZIENTE = paziente1_.ID_PAZIENTE
WHERE paziente1_.ID_SESSO = 1
 ORDER BY analisi0_.DATA_MODIFICA DESC
;

Comment: I tried also assigning 3GByte to mysql but without enhancement

Comment: datetime vs timestamp vs int should perform identically.

Comment: actually I'm using DATETIME for any date but I think the result is really poor, 75 seconds for an order by on 1.6 M rows seems to be too much, I hope solution will not be to insert ID_SESSO on table analisi :-)

Answer (score 0):

`(paziente5_.DATA_NASCITA IS NOT NULL OR paziente5_.DATA_NASCITA > 0)` does not make sense.  Perhaps you meant `AND`?  In that case, this would suffice:  `(paziente5_.DATA_NASCITA > 0)`.  In that case, this would probably be usable and help performance:

```
INDEX(nome, DATA_NASCITA)
```

It won't matter what datatype `DATA_NASCITA` is.

If that does not help enough, please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for each table so we can see if there are sufficient indexes to allow for *starting* with `paziente5_`.  This is what is needed for performance.

**More**

`(paziente5_.DATA_NASCITA IS NOT NULL OR paziente5_.DATA_NASCITA > 0)` is equivalent to `(paziente5_.DATA_NASCITA IS NOT NULL)`, but I suspect the optimizer does not realize that.  Anyway, your EXPLAIN implies that it does not care.

Could put provide the `EXPLAIN` for the test *without* `AND   (paziente5_.DATA_NASCITA IS NOT NULL OR paziente5_.DATA_NASCITA > 0)`.  Please make it clear which EXPLAIN goes with which test (with/without `ORDER BY` and with/without 'stupid' condition).

Comment: is not an and because this is a stupid condition, I've to take all, in that row I've also null values. what is strange is that I'm looking for a name this stupid condition help me, while if I'm looking for ID_SESSO this stupid condition double the select time from 40 to 75 seconds. I attached the table create script to the text above

Comment: @Etantonio: So DATA_NASCITA is a `DATE` and it must not be NULL in your query. But `paziente5_.DATA_NASCITA IS NOT NULL` is slow and adding `OR paziente5_.DATA_NASCITA > 0` makes it quicker??? Or what else are you trying to say?

Comment: I'm just trying to say that looking for "AND   (paziente5_.nome LIKE 'MARIA%')"     I spent 25 seconds less if I add also this stupid condition "
AND   (paziente5_.DATA_NASCITA IS NOT NULL OR paziente5_.DATA_NASCITA > 0)"    while looking for "paziente1_.ID_SESSO = 1" on the same table PAZIENTE the stupid condition produce a slower query. So finally I can say that  mysql by my point of view is not so simply predictable.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you add an index on table `Sessione` helping with the sorting:

```
create index idx_sessione_quick on sessione(id_tipo_sessione, data_sessione);
```

The first field in the index is for finding the records quickly, the second is for the order. You may even be able to speed this still up with a covering index:

```
create index idx_sessione_quick on sessione(id_tipo_sessione, data_sessione, 
                                            id_gel, numero_sessione);
```

Answer (score 0):

I did not see any real composite or covering indexes for your queries.  I offer the following to help optimize your query and even offer covering indexes to prevent going to raw data pages like your lookup tables.

```
table                  index
Paziente               ( nome, DATA_NASCITA, ID_PAZIENTE, ID_SESSO, ID_SPECIE )
Sessione               ( ID_SESSIONE, DATA_SESSIONE, ID_TIPO_SESSIONE )
tipo_sessione          ( ID_TIPO_SESSIONE, ID_METODICA_TIPO_METODICA )
metodica_tipo_metodica ( ID_METODICA_TIPO_METODICA, ID_METODICA
Metodica               ( ID_METODICA, metodica )
Analisi                ( ID_SESSIONE, ID_PAZIENTE, ID_PATOLOGICO, ID_TIPO_VALIDAZIONE )
Sesso                  ( ID_SESSO, sesso )
Specie                 ( ID_SPECIE, specie )
Patologico             ( ID_PATOLOGICO, patologico )
tipo_validazione       ( ID_TIPO_VALIDAZIONE, TIPO_VALIDAZIONE )
```

Next, I revised the query for two-part reason.  Put your paziente5 table first as that is the basis of your WHERE clause.  The index starting with the nome and DATA_NASCITA qualify your WHERE condition, yet the other fields are used to optimize the subsequent JOIN criteria.

Also, once joining to your sessione table, has the key element for the join, but THEN based on the ORDER BY column.  These should help.

```
SELECT 
      analisi0_.ID_ANALISI          AS col_0_0_,
      paziente5_.ID_PAZIENTE_LAB    AS col_1_0_,
      sessione1_.ID_GEL             AS col_2_0_,
      patologico8_.patologico       AS col_3_0_,
      tipovalida9_.TIPO_VALIDAZIONE AS col_4_0_,
      specie7_.specie               AS col_5_0_,
      analisi0_.campione            AS col_6_0_,
      analisi0_.tracciato           AS col_7_0_,
      paziente5_.cognome            AS col_8_0_,
      paziente5_.nome               AS col_9_0_,
      paziente5_.DATA_NASCITA       AS col_10_0_,
      sesso6_.sesso                 AS col_11_0_,
      sessione1_.NUMERO_SESSIONE    AS col_12_0_,
      sessione1_.DATA_SESSIONE      AS col_13_0_,
      metodica4_.metodica           AS col_14_0_
   FROM 
      Paziente paziente5_ 
         INNER JOIN Analisi analisi0_
            ON paziente5_.ID_PAZIENTE analisi0_.ID_PAZIENTE
            INNER JOIN Sessione sessione1_ 
               ON analisi0_.ID_SESSIONE = sessione1_.ID_SESSIONE
               INNER JOIN tipo_sessione tiposessio2_ 
                  ON sessione1_.ID_TIPO_SESSIONE = tiposessio2_.ID_TIPO_SESSIONE
                  INNER JOIN metodica_tipo_metodica metodicati3_ 
                     ON tiposessio2_.ID_METODICA_TIPO_METODICA = metodicati3_.ID_METODICA_TIPO_METODICA
                     INNER JOIN Metodica metodica4_ 
                        ON metodicati3_.ID_METODICA = metodica4_.ID_METODICA
            LEFT OUTER JOIN Patologico patologico8_ 
               ON analisi0_.ID_PATOLOGICO = patologico8_.ID_PATOLOGICO
            INNER JOIN tipo_validazione tipovalida9_ 
               ON analisi0_.ID_TIPO_VALIDAZIONE = tipovalida9_.ID_TIPO_VALIDAZIONE
         INNER JOIN Sesso sesso6_ 
            ON paziente5_.ID_SESSO = sesso6_.ID_SESSO
         INNER JOIN Specie specie7_ 
            ON paziente5_.ID_SPECIE = specie7_.ID_SPECIE
   WHERE 
          1 = 1
      AND ( paziente5_.nome LIKE 'MARIA%' )
      AND (   paziente5_.DATA_NASCITA IS NOT NULL 
           OR paziente5_.DATA_NASCITA > 0)
   ORDER BY 
      sessione1_.DATA_SESSIONE ASC 
   LIMIT 
      20;
```

One FINAL attempt for optimizing is add the keyword

SELECT STRAIGHT_JOIN  ... rest of query.

STRAIGHT_JOIN tells the engine to run in the order presented.  I have seen it work in many situations, but not in others, that is why I left it out by default and you can try adding in after.

The reason for the delay in the order by is that the engine needs to return ALL QUALIFIED records first, THEN sort based on your order by, but you need to get to your sessione table quicker based on your paziente qualifier conditions.